# String.format with StreamReader in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send an email for Reset password implementation using SMTP concept in MVC. I created a email template txt file as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/CSS">
        .btn {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 6px 12px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          line-height: 1.42857143;
          text-align: center;
          white-space: nowrap;
          vertical-align: middle;
          -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
              touch-action: manipulation;
          cursor: pointer;
          background-image: none;

          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .btn:focus,
        .btn:active:focus,
        .btn.active:focus,
        .btn.focus,
        .btn:active.focus,
        .btn.active.focus {
          outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
          outline-offset: -2px;
        }
        .btn:hover,
        .btn:focus,
        .btn.focus {
          color: #333;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .btn:active,
        .btn.active {
          background-image: none;
          outline: 0;
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
                  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
        }
        .btn-default {
            background-color:#EE1A30;
            color:white;
        }
        .btn-default:hover {
          color: black;
          background-color: white;
          border-color: #C7C7C7;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="width:75%;">
            <div style="width:100%;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <div style="background-color:black;">
                    <img src="\images\Logo.jpg"> 
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:#CECECE;padding:2% 19%;">      
                    <div style="background-color:white">
                        <div style="background-color:#EE1A30;padding:2% 7%;text-align:center;"> 
                            <label style="font-weight:bold;color:white;font-size:15px">FORGOT PASSWORD</label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding:4%;font-size:14px;align:center">
                            <label style="">Hi, {0}</label><br><br>
                            <span>You recently requested to reset your password for your account. Click the button below to reset it.</span><br><br>
                            <div>
                                <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"Reset Password\" class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="text-decoration:none;">Reset your password</a>
                            </div><br>
                            <span>If you did not request a password reset, please ignore this email. This password reset is valid only for next 30 minutes.</span><br><br><br><br>
                            <span>Thanks,</span><br>
                            <span>Team</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</body>
```

In the controller, am trying to send email by reading the text from sampleText.txt.

```
string Body = string.Empty;
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sample@domain.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailID));
            mailMessage.Subject = "Reset password";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/folder1/folder2/") + "sampleText.txt"))
            {
                Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            mailMessage.Body = string.Format(Body, userName, Url.Action("action", "controller", new { Token = token, Email = emailID }));
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

It throws an exception as "Input string was not in a correct format." on the below line, in which am passing the username as first parameter and URL to redirect as second parameter.

```
mailMessage.Body = string.Format(Body, userName, Url.Action("action", "controller", new { Token = token, Email = emailID }));
```

Help me with this issue.

Comment: Your `Body` contains `{` and `}` that aren't part of the format.  You need to escape those.

Comment: Yes. You mean in the CSS style part. Then how can I apply just a long CSS styles for my content? Is there any other way?

Comment: Like I said, you need to escape them.

Comment: Yup. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

To escape `{` and `}` in a `String.Format`, you need to double them up:

Use `{{` when you want the result to contain a `{` literal.  And use `}}` when you want the result to contain a `}` literal.

That's all there is to it.